# Rails / ActiveRecord: field normalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to remove the commas from a field in a model. I want the user to type a number, i.e. 10,000 and that number should be stored in the database as 10000. I was hoping that I could do some model-side normalization to remove the comma. I don't want to depend on the view or controller to properly format my data.

I tried:

```
before_validation :normalize

def normalize 
 self['thenumber'] = self['thenumber'].to_s.gsub(',','')
end
```

no worky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with doing it that way is that for a while, the non-normalized stuff will exist in the object; if you have code that works on the attributes before stuff gets normalised, then that will be a problem.

You could define a setter:

```
def thenumber=(value)
  # normalise stuff here, call write_attribute
end
```

Unfortunately I think a lot of the Rails form stuff writes the attributes directly, which is one of the reasons I don't tend to use it.

Or you could normalise the params in the controller before you pass them through.

Comment: Yes, I've resigned myself to normalize the params in the controller before they get into AR at all...

Answer (score 8):

http://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer looks like a promising solution to this common problem. Here are a few examples from the home page:

```
  # By default it will strip leading and trailing whitespace
  # and set to nil if blank.
  normalize_attributes :author, :publisher

  # Using one of our predefined normalizers.
  normalize_attribute  :price, :with => :currency

  # You can also define your normalization block inline.
  normalize_attribute :title do |value|
    value.is_a?(String) ? value.titleize.strip : value
  end
```

So in your case you might do something like this:

```
  normalize_attribute :title do |value|
    value.to_s.gsub(',', '')
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you're doing it right. This test passes:

```
test "should remove commas from thenumber" do
  f = Foo.new(:thenumber => "10,000")
  f.save
  f = Foo.find(f.id)
  assert f.thenumber == "10000"    
end
```

And I used your code.

```
 class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :normalize

  def normalize 
    self['thenumber'] = self['thenumber'].to_s.gsub(',','')
  end

 end
```

Now, my schema is set up for thenumber to be a string though, not an integer.

```
Started
.
Finished in 0.049666 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
```

If you wanted to store this in the db as an integer, then you definitely need to override the setter:

```
 def thenumber=(value)
   self['thenumber'] = value.to_s.gsub(',','').to_i
 end
```

If you do it your way, with an integer column, it gets truncated by AR....

```
>> f.thenumber = "10,000"
=> "10,000"
>> f.thenumber
=> 10
```

That's a little-known thing with Ruby and integers... it auto-casts by truncating anything that's no longer an integer.

```
irb(main):004:0> i = "155-brian-hogan".to_i
=> 155
```

Can be cool for things like

```
/users/155-brian-hogan

@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

But not so cool for what you're doing.

So either change the col to a string and use the filter, or change the setter :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Rails 7.1 introduced [`ActiveRecord::Base::normalizes`](https://github.com/jonathanhefner/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/normalization.rb)

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  normalizes :email, with: ->(email) { email.strip.downcase }
end
```

It invokes before validation

It is safe because doesn't (but optionally can) apply to `nil`

It works with both persistence and finder methods

```rb
User.create(email: " ASDF@ExAmPLE.com \n")
# => #<User email: "asdf@example.com">

User.find_by(email: "\nasdf@examplE.CoM \t")
# => #<User email: "asdf@example.com">
```

If you need apply normalization for `nil` values too, use `apply_to_nil: true` option

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  normalizes :email, with: ->(email) { email&.strip&.downcase || "default@email.com" }, apply_to_nil: true
end
```

(`"default@email.com"` email will be assigned in `nil` case)

If you have legacy non-normalized record, you can normalize it with `ActiveRecord::Base#normalize_attribute`

```
user.email # => "legacy@EMAIL.com  "
user.normalize_attribute(:email)
user.email # => "legacy@email.com"
user.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Does ruby let you interchange between a . and [''] ?
I don't know, I'll try later, but I think you are supposed to use .

```
self.thenumber = self.thenumber.to_s.gsub(',','')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return true from your before_validation method, otherwise if the expression being assigned to self['thenumber'] ends up being nil or false, the data will not be saved, per the Rails documention:

> If a before_* callback returns false,
>   all the later callbacks and the
>   associated action are cancelled.

Ostensibly, you are trying to normalize here then check the result of the normalization with your Rails validations, which will decide if nil/false/blank are okay or not.

```
before_validation :normalize

def normalize 
  self['thenumber'] = self['thenumber'].to_s.gsub(',','')
  return true
end
```

Comment: just adding the note I wish I'd seen here earlier...  before_validation happens after type casting, so if thenumber is a number type and you are doing something like stripping $ and , symbols you need self['thenumber'] = thenumber_before_type_cast.to_s.gsub(...)  The before_type_cast version is autogenerated, and you need to_s in case it's already a number.